# Error when POSTing a form to auth route (MethodNotAllowedHttpException)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I am trying to POST a form BEFORE user authentication.
User inputs data into a form and POST it to the route protected by auth:

> Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
>       Route::post('v2/payment/start/','PaymentController@generic');
>
> });

If a user IS authenticated BEFORE the POST, the request is processed OK.
If a user is NOT authenticated, user gets the login form, enters login password and receives the error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException".

What could be the cause of this?
In my LoginController I have:

> return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());

so, the user should be redirected OK.

Where could be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after user is authenticated, they will be redirected using `GET` method (redirections always use GET method). So you can try to use:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'v2/payment/start/','PaymentController@generic');
```

instead of

```
Route::post('v2/payment/start/','PaymentController@generic');
```

to make this route working with both `GET` and `POST` methods.